# Store the changes done to database in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I want to store the changes done to database in a structure or something so that I can refer them anytime after the database context is over. I am using Entity Framework in C#  and underlying database in SQL Server.

The information that I want to store is

- The executing database context
- The table name
- Previous value of updated column
- New value of updated column
- Id of row added or deleted.
- operation performed( update or delete or add )

Currently I am storing them in form of string. But the problem is, using this approach I can not reproduce the linq query so that I can revert the changes.

How shall I proceed in this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can observe change tracker (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.changetracker%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.ChangeTracker) before `SaveChanges`, gather IDs of newly added items after it, and this info in your own model to playback reversal actions later.

Comment: @Dennis Can I use change tracker after the context (SaveChanges) is over ?

Comment: `SaveChanges` resets change tracker state (that is, throwing away old changes data). Of course, you can access it after `SaveChanges`, but it will be "empty".

Comment: So you can copy stuff from tracker before SaveChanges, to be used after SaveChanges.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks Dennis. I want to retain the changes after save changes. Is there a way to do that or can I store them somewhere else ?

Comment: @Dennis Thanks Dennis.It helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can observe [change tracker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.changetracker%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.ChangeTracker) before [`SaveChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges), and store changes in your own model. Later, use this model to to playback reversal actions.

E.g., given this context:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

you can write such a class:

```
public class SampleContextMemento
{
    private IEnumerable<Person> addedPeople;
    private IEnumerable<Person> deletedPeople;

    private IEnumerable<T> GetEntitiesByState<T>(SampleContext context, EntityState state)
        where T : class
    {
        return context.ChangeTracker
            .Entries<T>()
            .Where(_ => _.State == state)
            .Select(_ => _.Entity)
            .ToList();
    }

    public void RecordChanges(SampleContext context)
    {
        addedPeople = GetEntitiesByState<Person>(context, EntityState.Added);
        deletedPeople = GetEntitiesByState<Person>(context, EntityState.Deleted);
    }

    public void RollbackChanges(SampleContext context)
    {
        // delete added entities
        if (addedPeople != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in addedPeople)
            {
                context.People.Remove(context.People.Find(item.Id));
            }
        }

        if (deletedPeople != null)
        {
            // add deleted entities
            foreach (var item in deletedPeople)
            {
                context.People.Add(item);
            }
        }

        // save reverted changes
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var memento = new SampleContextMemento();

// make changes
using (var context = new SampleContext())
{
    // add some entities
    context.People.Add(new Person { Id = 100, Name = "John" });
    // remove some
    context.People.Remove(context.People.Find(1));
    // saving changes in our memento to rollback them later
    memento.RecordChanges(context);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

// rollback them
using (var context = new SampleContext())
{
    memento.RollbackChanges(context);
}
```

Of course, universal solution will be more complex, but this should give you basic idea.

Comment: what if I want to do it after scope is over. i.e after closing brace of  context. How can I get the context again.

Comment: @MadhurMaurya: I've updated answer. This one works with different instances of context.